# To make appear progressively letters in the disorder

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to do it in xml? Is there an implementation that has this mode?

**Example (fading, not binary):**

1. H__LO__O_L_
2. HEL_O_WO_LD
3. HELLO_WORLD

*_ = empty*

The only way I've found is to create a text for each letter and add an animation with a for each letter, but it's not practical.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do it in xml? Is there an implementation that has
>   this mode?

I'm not sure about the XML implementation, however you can achieve the desired effect a bit easier than the for loop with a `Spannable`

You can use a `SpannableString` and set the color of the *empty* letters the same as their background so they appear as transparent.

Then animate them by changing the `textColor` to the final one.

You can use the following function:

```
private void showTextAnimated(final int[] positions){
        final SpannableString myText = new SpannableString(mTextView.getText());
        for(int i = 0; i< positions.length; i++){
            myText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.TRANSPARENT),positions[i] ,positions[i]+1 , Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
        mTextView.setText(myText);

    ValueAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofArgb(Color.BLACK);
    anim.setRepeatCount(positions.length);
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        int counter = 0;
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            //no-op
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            //no-op
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            //no-op
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            myText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK),positions[counter] ,positions[counter]+1 , Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            mTextView.setText(myText);
            counter++;
        }
    });
    anim.start();
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    int[] lettersToAnimate = new int[] {2,9,8,3};
    mTextView = findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    showTextAnimated(lettersToAnimate);

}
```

You can also have a look at [HTextView](https://github.com/hanks-zyh/HTextView), the fade plugin of this library makes the letters fade-in randomly:

> Animation effects to text, not really textview

Comment: Great! But how animate Letter in Spannable string?

Comment: @AudricPazza You can check my update and customize it to your needs, but the general idea is there

Comment: Very good. But I do not exactly want that. I want my different anim_fade.xml which one of the android: duration = "500" diffferents, to be used at the same time on the letters of the table int [] lettersToAnimate. Example: Letter1.anim_fade1; Letter2.anim_fade2; (...) How to do ?

Comment: The question specified appear not fade-in. To have them fade-in I can't think of another solution apart from the one you're already using, ie. have multiple `TextView`s although you can improve it a bit and make the process dynamic by generating the views at runtime. I also updated my answer with a library that you might find useful.